# How can I read the children of a specific parent in Linq / XML

Tags: xml, linq

I have a very straight forward simple xml file that looks like this.

I want to get all the rows under hobby, and then I want to get all the rows under songs. So get row by what its under. Can anyone help, thank you!

```
<sasjamal>
  <hobbies>
    <row>...</row>
    <row>...</row>
  </hobbies>
  <songs>
    <row>...</row>
    <row>...</row>
  </songs>
</sasjamal>
```

This is what I have tried

```
var rows = xdoc.Root.Descendants("hobbies").Elements("row"); 
var rows = xdoc.Root.Descendants("songs").Elements("row");
```

Comment: You've been on SO for 3 years - what have you tried?

Comment: var rows = xdoc.Root.Descendants("hobbies").Elements("row");
var rows = xdoc.Root.Descendants("songs").Elements("row");
That is what I have tried.

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: The code you posted will work.  Each line will return an `IEnumerable<XElement>` collection.  I.e., `var rows = xdoc.Root.Descendants("hobbies").Elements("row");` will give you a collection with 2 `XElement` in it - one for each `<row>`.

Comment: So all in all, you've still not really asked anything. "I want this, I tried that".... sooo...?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, by "get all the rows" you mean the string values!? If so, then here's your solution:

```
var hobbies = xdoc.Root.Descendants("hobbies").Elements("row").Select(e => e.Value);
var songs = xdoc.Root.Descendants("songs").Elements("row").Select(e => e.Value);
```

Comment: XDocument seriously rules! ;-)